# sorting 2 array the same way

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays `double sales[]` and `String sales1[]` that store the name for the sales. I need to sort `sales[]` in descending order and `sales1[]` has to match it, but currently when `sales[]` are sorted some of the `sales1[]` don't match.

`sales1[]=("kapas","redang","perhentian","tenggol","lang tengah")`

here's my code currently

```
public void sort(double sales[], String sales1[]) {
    int i, j;
    double temp;
    String temp1;

    for (i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < sales.length; j++) {
            if (sales[i] < sales[j]) {
                temp1 = sales1[i];
                sales1[i] = sales1[j];
                sales1[j] = temp1;

                temp = sales[i];
                sales[i] = sales[j];
                sales[j] = temp;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Save yourself a lot of trouble and create a simple class that holds the name and price/amount of the sale and have _one_ array with objects of that class

Comment: Sorting two arrays with no apparent relation between them? If the orders match before sorting, how about joining them together first? Edit: Joakims solution is better!

Comment: You can use `sort` method from `java.util.Arrays`

Comment: *when sales[] are sorted some of the sales1[] don't match* - could you add an example `sales[]` which produces the issue? Right now there is a `sales1[]` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You will create a new `class Sale implements Comparable<Sale>`.
- This class will have a `double` member and a `String` member.
- You will give those members meaningful names, like `amount` and
  `name` instead of `member1` and `member2`.
- This class will also contain a `CompareTo` method to compare one
  instance with another.  It will be implemented by comparing the
  `double` member.
- You will pass your `sort()` method an array of `Sale` instead of the individual arrays you are passing it now.
- Your `sort()` method will simply consist of one line, which delegates to `Arrays.sort()` to quick-sort your array instead of rolling your own extremely
  inefficient bubblesort.